# Importing .csv file into R studio cloud

Tags: r, read.csv

I am trying to import a .csv file into R studio cloud using this code

```
data<-read.csv("C:/Users/piyus/Downloads/202004-divvy-tripdata/202004-divvy-tripdata.csv")
```

When executing this code following error is appearing
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
cannot open file 'C:/Users/piyus/Downloads/202004-divvy-tripdata/202004-divvy-tripdata.csv': No such file or directory

The same code when executed on R studio is working fine.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that "RStudio cloud"  (I'm not sure what you mean by that) doesn't know where your C drive is.  And even if it did, wouldn't be allowed to access it.  Upload your CSV to the cloud and modify your path to reflect its new location.  If that doesn't work, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) inclusing the output of `sessionInfo()` from your cloud session.

Comment: I believe what you're attempting may not be feasible. I usually upload the file to the working directory first, and then read it into R using data <- read.csv('my_csv.csv'). See here <https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-can-i-import-csv-file-in-the-data-frame-in-posit-cloud/153028/4>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RStudio Cloud is a lovely product, and valuable for testing as it gives you a (totally free for a few hours, else paid) compute environment *in the cloud*.  I found it handy for my students while we had a multi-year pilot.

But we have to stress "in the cloud" here. And your CSV files lives, per your path, in the `"C:/Users/piyus/Downloads/` directory.  Which is ... very much on laptop or PC and not in the cloud.

So there are *two* things you can do:

1. Upload the file. As I recall the 'File' menu, commonly in the bottom-right, has a 'upload' button.  You can then upload either the whole Divvy data folder, or just the file.
2. Change your script to access the (presumably public) resource you got the Divvy data from in the first place and bypass your computer for the data.

Both should work.